# How to call the method from javascript file inside from the typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-definition

This is my javascript class: TestClass.js

```
/**
 * http://usejsdoc.org/
 */
export class TestClass{
    constructor(){

    }

    echo(){
        alert("Echo")
    }
}
```

This is my definition file:test.d.ts

```
/**
 * http://usejsdoc.org/
 */

declare class TestClass{
     public echo():void;
}
```

This is my ts main file: entry.ts

```
import * as go from "gojs";
import * as test from "./TestClass"    

window.addEventListener( "load", delay );

function delay() {

    var testClass=new test.TestClass()
    TestClass.echo();

}
```

And when I try to build it with the npm run build

```
ERROR in /home/voffka/Documents/projects/typescript-tutorial/r-diagram1/r-diagram/src/entry.ts(9,15)
TS2339: Property 'echo' does not exist on type 'typeof TestClass'.
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you mean to call `testClass.echo()`?  Otherwise you're declaring a variable and then never using it, and trying to call the method statically.

Comment: Yes, I need to use not static method

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
import * as go from "gojs";
import * as test from "./TestClass"    

window.addEventListener( "load", delay );

function delay() {

    var testClass=new test()
    test.echo();

}
```